# Working with firewall-protected server through ssh (dynamic IP)

Tags: debian, ssh, firewall, webserver

I need to work on a Debian 6 server through SSH. The server is firewall-protected and SSH connections are filtered based on the user IP.

Unfortunately I have an ISP provider with dynamic IP - it's changing every day.

I managed to write a simple script that reads an IP stored in a file and adds it to firewall's exception list. But right now every time I connect to server I need to:

- send my IP to the server
- login to web console
- restart firewall

Is there any simpler/more automated way to manage firewall protected SSH connections when I have dynamic IP?

Answer (score 3):

Currently I can think of three ways:

The first is to use `knockd` - my favorite - (http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock/) and configure a port sequence only you remember and let `knockd` open SSH for the IP address you are referring from. `knockd` is available in a debian package and a sample configuration (`/etc/knockd.conf`) can be:

```
[options]
logfile = /var/log/knockd.log

[opencloseSSH]
sequence      = 2221,2222,2223
seq_timeout   = 5
tcpflags      = syn
start_command = /usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -i enp0s8 -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
cmd_timeout   = 15
stop_command  = /usr/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -i enp0s8 -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

This way `knockd` will listen for a sequence on the specified ports (they might even be the same) and will open the port if the sequence is hit within 5 seconds. After 15 seconds the rule is removed again so a succesfull login needs to be started within those 15 seconds.

The second one is based on dynamic DNS combined with refreshing an iptables chain regularly:

```
iptables -N SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j SSH
```

Schedule a cronjob to run the following script, for example, every minute:

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F SSH 
iptables -A SSH -s ddns-entry.com -j ACCEPT
```

This way the SSH chain is flushed and refilled every interval you have chosen.

Alternatively you can create a (password protected) web page on your Debian 6 host which will allow you to enter an IP address which is saved into `/tmp/currip` for instance. Schedule a cron job to run every minute - or, even better, use inotify/incron - and check the `/tmp/currip` file and alter the `iptables` rule to use the address listed in the file. Since it very depends on the kind of web stack you are using I do not list a sample here.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer: use [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)

There are some free (for private use) options around like [noip.com](http://www.noip.com/), or [dyndns.org](http://dyn.com/dns/)

**EDIT:**
You have to create a script (for example) that updates the `iptables` rules constantly, I forgot to mention that earlier. (Thanks to @Lambert)

**EDIT2:**
I don't use a beautiful solution like that, but you could try out [this](http://diginc.us/linux/2010/using-iptables-with-dynamic-ip-hostnames-like-dyndns-org/) neat python script.

Comment: Dynamic DNS will not work since `iptables` will resolve the host and uses the IP address within the rules.

Comment: @Lambert yeah, but what's the problem with that? I use dyn DNS within multiple iptables-scripts and it works without any errors. You have to update the iptables rules constantly, of course (forgot to mention that...sorry)

Comment: There is no problem with it but just to answer to use dynamic DNS is not a solution and simply does not work. I like your edit, especially the link to the script.